# Error When Installing Data Migration Tool

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am getting the following error when trying to install the data migration tool

```
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.1

  Problem 1
- The requested package magento/data-migration-tool 2.1 exists as magento/data-migration-tool[2.0.0, 2.0.2, 2.0.5, 2.0.7] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```

Any ideas? There is an open issue on Github for this (https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/104) but any help is appreciated.

Below is what I get when requiring data-migration-tool:2.0.7

```
  Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install magento/data-migration-tool 2.0.7
- Conclusion: don't install magento/data-migration-tool 2.0.7
- Conclusion: don't install magento/data-migration-tool 2.0.7|remove magento/framework 100.1.0
- Conclusion: don't install magento/data-migration-tool 2.0.7|don't install magento/framework 100.1.0
- Conclusion: don't install magento/data-migration-tool 2.0.7|don't install magento/framework 100.1.0
- Installation request for magento/data-migration-tool 2.0.7 -> satisfiable by magento/data-migration-tool[2.0.7].
- magento/data-migration-tool 2.0.7 requires magento/framework ~100.0.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.0, 100.0.2].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.0, 100.0.3].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.0, 100.0.4].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.0, 100.0.5].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.0, 100.0.6].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.0, 100.0.7].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.0, 100.0.8].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.0, 100.0.9].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.0, 100.0.2].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.0, 100.0.3].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.0, 100.0.4].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.0, 100.0.5].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.0, 100.0.6].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.0, 100.0.7].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.0, 100.0.8].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.0, 100.0.9].
- Installation request for magento/framework (locked at 100.1.0) -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.0].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the data migration tool for 2.1 has not been released yet and will be out in roughly 2 weeks.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5244

Answer (score 0):

That's not an issue or a bug, you're requesting a version of that package that does not exist. Why don't you request the latest existing version:

```
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.0.7
```

Comment: I editing my question above with the error I get when using 2.0.7

Comment: @qrider then it seems that 2.0.7 is not compatible with magento 2.1 so you'll have to wait until magento releases a new version or downgrade to 2.0.7